# How can I automate updating of my github account?

Tags: git, github

I push to a bare repo when I am ready to update my production server.  The bare repository has a hook that checks the code out to the working directory.

```
#post-receive hook
git --work-tree=working_path --git-dir=bare_repo.git checkout -f
```

I want to update my github account on each production update.  I was hoping I could do something like

```
git --work-tree=remote_github --git-dir=/bare_repo.git checkout -f
```

but I think `--work-tree` expects a path not a remote url.

If my remote github url is `https://github.com/foo/foo.git` what hook could I implement to have it update?

[git checkout documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) does not seem to cover the options so knowing where I can read about `--work-tree` and `--git-dir`.

Also, the [online version of git pro](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) had a very limited section on hooks.

Comment: Do you want to `push` to your github repository in the hook?

Comment: The question does not specify, so whatever way you think is best.   Please let me know.